# How can I extract the bins from seaborn's KDE distplot object?

Tags: python, grouping, histogram, seaborn, discrete-mathematics

## Background

I am trying to group ~11,000 genes of a species of plant (*Arabidopsis thaliana*), by data I have of their change in [expression levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_Atlas), in response to light exposure.

The raw values, per gene, are continuous random variables, but I wish to discretise the values to have, say, 20 discrete classes.

So instead of:

```
change_in_expression = array([-2.2, -1.1, -1.2, ...,  0.6, -1. , -0.9])
```

I have class outputs:

```
change_in_expression = array(["3_to_4","2_to_3","1_to_2",...])
```

---

## What I have tried

I plot the distribution with `seaborn's distplot()`, which I believe uses a [KDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation):

```
import seaborn as sns

d = array([-2.2, -1.1, -1.2, ...,  0.6, -1. , -0.9]) # = change_in_expression

dis = sns.distplot(d, fit=stats.laplace, kde=False)

plt.title("Distribution of Differential Expression")
plt.xlabel("Log2FoldChange in expression")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

[image]

And I am aware that `matplotlib.pyplot's` `hist()` allows you to extract bins, when the default settings "automatically" generate these groupings...

---

## Summary Question

The question is, how can I group my genes? This is a broader question than just asking for the `seaborn` version of `matplotlib's` `hist()`... since `seaborn's` `distplot` uses a **KDE**.

Doesn't really seem like I can get the bins from the `ax` object created by seaborn, by looking at the methods available from:

```
dir(sns.distplot(d, fit=stats.laplace, kde=False)
```

I guess, one way would be to inspect the guts of seaborn's `distplot` source code, to figure out how they bin the data prior to plotting... but that is way beyond my unicorn skillset...

Comment: A distplot is a histogram plot with a plot of a kde on top. Those are independent. Since there is no "grouping" for KDE, I'm unsure what the question really aims at?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, thank you for your edit. And your deeper understanding: I suppose then the *question* is, what algorithm decides binning, I suppose I could hunt around for the histogram part of the source code. ThanK pal!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seaborn calls `pyplot.hist`, which in turn calls `numpy.histogram`. So one can check what seaborn uses as `bins` argument if none is specified. I.e. with `a` being the data,

```
bins = min(_freedman_diaconis_bins(a), 50)
```

where [1](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/5498cdb2f145b15a85adac0c8ff233656f52a943/seaborn/distributions.py#L24)

```
def _freedman_diaconis_bins(a):
    """Calculate number of hist bins using Freedman-Diaconis rule."""
    # From https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/798/
    a = np.asarray(a)
    if len(a) < 2:
        return 1
    h = 2 * iqr(a) / (len(a) ** (1 / 3))
    # fall back to sqrt(a) bins if iqr is 0
    if h == 0:
        return int(np.sqrt(a.size))
    else:
        return int(np.ceil((a.max() - a.min()) / h))
```

and `iqr` [2](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/5498cdb2f145b15a85adac0c8ff233656f52a943/seaborn/utils.py#L359)

```
def iqr(a):
    """Calculate the IQR for an array of numbers."""
    a = np.asarray(a)
    q1 = stats.scoreatpercentile(a, 25)
    q3 = stats.scoreatpercentile(a, 75)
    return q3 - q1
```

All of this should roughly be the same as

```
bins = min(len(numpy.histogram_bin_edges(a, bins="fd")), 50)
```

or

```
bins = 50 if len(numpy.histogram_bin_edges(a, bins="fd")) > 50 else "fd"
```

then passing `bins` to `pyplot.hist`,

```
plt.hist(a, bins=bins)
```

Comment: Clearly you have gone beyond the call of duty by looking the source yourself, that is amazing... as a new starter for Stack I really cannot believe how helpful you all are. 

I have now researched freedman diaconis and understand the IQR dependency. 

I tried to +1 but I'm still  <15 points, so I'll keep you in my good books and +1 when I have that privilege. Great work.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered already but if really need to extract the bins from a histogram, or bar plot, (things that use patches) you can use this function. I use np.unique() because sometimes you may have multiple bar plots. if you have multiple, this assumes they are overlapping bar plots. I think if you `'dodge'` using seaborn this method will not work since it is literally grabbing the placements of the patches (rectangles).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

def get_bins_from_ax(ax=None):
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()
    bins_from_patches = np.unique([ax.patches[0].get_x()]+[bar.get_x()+bar.get_width() for bar in ax.patches])
    return bins_from_patches
```